# Organize alternative names (nicknames, aliases) in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Say you have some nodes in your model that may go by multiple alternative names, but all the names refer to the same object.

For example, you may want to be able to query the "World" node by using name "World" in one context, whereas in different context you want to find the same node quickly also by the name "Global".

Is it optimal to organize this information in the form of string array property `aliases` like this? :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add World to your aliases you can use the legacy node_auto_index to index that aliases field

which will index each value individually and the query it with

Start n=node:node_auto_index(aliases="Global")
return n

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use [Lucene](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing-add.html) for that.
You could index the same property several times with different names.

You can then query the index in the way you want through Java APIs or Cypher.
For instance:

```
START n = node:myIndex(myProperty="ALIAS_1"), 
      m = node:myIndex(myProperty="ALIAS_2")
[...]
```

Comment: Thank you, can you kindly demonstrate a sample `Cypher` statement how to set up those multiple indices on the "World" node?

Comment: Given above, can I specifically write `START n = node:Geography(name="World"), m = node:Alias(aliases="Global") [...]` ? Is in your snippet `myIndex` equivalent to neo4j's label?

Comment: Yes, you can write this. `myIndex` is a Lucene index (this was the way to go with neo4j before version 2.0 - no labels at the time) you can create with Java APIs: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing.html.