# neo4j multiple indexed names for Node with schema indexes

Tags: indexing, neo4j

Follow up on question: [Organize alternative names (nicknames, aliases) in neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327139/organize-alternative-names-nicknames-aliases-in-neo4j)

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Node(name);
CREATE (n:Node {name: ["nameA", "nameB"]});
MATCH (n:Node {name: "nameA"}) return n;
```

1. Indexing the name property of Nodes.
2. Using a collection (array) of names for the name of a node.
3. Searching for one of these names and returning the node.

Do I have to use legacy indexing or can this be achieved through regular indexing?

I'm asking since the original question is over 3 years old and I'd assume a similar feature may have been added.

Answer (score 0):

No, "normal" indexing does not support that.

But you could alter your data model to allow multiple `Name` nodes to point to the same `Node` node, and index `:Name(name)`. Something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Name(name);

CREATE
  (node:Node {id: 123}),
  (:Name {name: "nameA"})-[:NAME_OF]->(node),
  (:Name {name: "nameB"})-[:NAME_OF]->(node);

MATCH (:Name {name: "nameA"})-[:NAME_OF]->(node) return node;
```